# What are the possibilities for speeding up this function?

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, tree

I am trying to speed up the following function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.List (foldl1')
import System.Random
import qualified Data.List as L

data Tree a = AB (Tree a) (Tree a) | A (Tree a) | B (Tree a) | C !a
    deriving Show

merge :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
merge (C x) _               = C x
merge _ (C y)               = C y
merge (A ta) (A tb)         = A (merge ta tb)
merge (A ta) (B tb)         = AB ta tb
merge (A ta) (AB tb tc)     = AB (merge ta tb) tc
merge (B ta) (A tb)         = AB tb ta
merge (B ta) (B tb)         = B (merge ta tb)
merge (B ta) (AB tb tc)     = AB tb (merge ta tc)
merge (AB ta tb) (A tc)     = AB (merge ta tc) tb
merge (AB ta tb) (B tc)     = AB ta (merge tb tc)
merge (AB ta tb) (AB tc td) = AB (merge ta tc) (merge tb td)
```

In order to stress its performance, I've implemented sort using `merge`:

```
fold ab a b c list = go list where
    go (AB a' b') = ab (go a') (go b')
    go (A a')     = a (go a')
    go (B b')     = b (go b')
    go (C x)      = c x

mergeAll :: [Tree a] -> Tree a
mergeAll = foldl1' merge

foldrBits :: (Word32 -> t -> t) -> t -> Word32 -> t
foldrBits cons nil word = go 32 word nil where
    go 0 w !r = r
    go l w !r = go (l-1) (shiftR w 1) (cons (w.&.1) r)

word32ToTree :: Word32 -> Tree Word32
word32ToTree w = foldrBits cons (C w) w where
    cons 0 t = A t
    cons 1 t = B t

toList = fold (++) id id (\ a -> [a])

sort = toList . mergeAll . map word32ToTree

main = do
    is <- mapM (const randomIO :: a -> IO Word32) [0..500000]
    print $ sum $ sort is
```

The performance came up quite good from the go, around 2.5x slower than `Data.List`'s `sort`. Nothing that I did sped that up further, though: inlining several functions, bang annotations in many places, `UNPACK` on `C !a`. Is there any way to speed this function up?

Comment: Are you including the cost of `map word32ToTree` in the cost of `sort`? How fast is `mergeAll` if you force `map word32ToTree` first? How fast is it if you force the result with something other than `toList`?

Comment: I don't know about speed, but as a matter of style, you could implement the typeclass "Foldable" so you could call base function without converting to list

Comment: @Cirdec I haven't thought of any of that.

Comment: @Bruno true, that's just a matter of changing the types.

Comment: what kind of tree is that? what are trees with that shape used for?

Comment: @ErikAllik I just came with this because it allows `log(N)` insertion and querying for "nearest neighbors" of unsigned ints. I'm using that structure as a quadtree, in that sense. I don't know if it has a name. There are probably better ways to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely have too many thunks allocated. I'll show how to analyze the code:

```
merge (A ta) (A tb)         = A (merge ta tb)
```

Here you allocate constructor `A` with one argument, which is a thunk. Can you say when the `merge ta tb` chunk will be forced? Probably only at the very end, when the resulting tree is used. Try to add a bang to each argument of each `Tree` constructor to ensure it is spine-strict:

```
data Tree a = AB !(Tree a) !(Tree a) | A !(Tree a) | B !(Tree a) | C !a
```

The next example:

```
go l w !r = go (l-1) (shiftR w 1) (cons (w.&.1) r)
```

Here you are allocating a thunk for `l-1`, `shifrR w 1` and `cons (w.&.1) r`. The first one will be forced on the next iterations when comparing `l` with `o`, the second one will be forced when forcing the 3d thunk in the next iteration (`w` is used here), and the 3rd thunk is forced on the next iteration because of a bang on `r`. So probably this particular clause it OK.

Comment: Good. Adding bang annotations on the spine of the Tree improved the performance almost two fold. I was told before the rule of thumb is strict on leaves, lazy on spine. Any reason this particular instance doesn't follow the rule?

Comment: @Viclib I don't know any formal study on spine strict vs spine lazy structures. But I think it depends mostly on usage pattern. Instead of making the tree spine strict, you can fix `merge` to force spine.

Comment: @Viclib At the second glance you can get a performance boost from spine lazy tree. E.g. instead of creating 500000 trees before merging them, you can build the result forcing only necessary parts of the trees. That way you can make allocations short living. But that requires careful design of `sort`.

Comment: `sort` will not be used that much, but `buildTree = mergeAll . map word32ToTree` will. I think what you said applies to it. I'll think about that, thank you. If I follow this route, I should also manually fix the thunks on the `merge` function, as you proposed, correct?

Comment: I've attempted [this design](http://lpaste.net/142077) using your last idea, but it seems like not creating 500000 trees doesn't change the performance. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Viclib sorry, I was not clear. You are not creating all the trees ahead of time in the spine strict version. You have an accumulator (the merged tree), and on each step `foldl1'` creates the next tree (fully evaluating it because it is spine strict) and merge with accumulator. The idea was not to create the next tree fully, but do it lazily during merging. Though I don't know whether it is possible or even useful.